# How to find the class of a control when it's defined in another class

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using 2 classes that contains buttons; I added their buttons in my main form, and now I want to do something when the user clicks on one of them. For example, if the user clicks on the button that's defined in class1, the text of all the buttons that are defined in class1 should change to "class1". Actually, I need to find the class of a button to change other variables in that class.

Comment: I'm having a hard time trying to understand your question.  Do you think you could hit the edit button and try to clear it up a bit, bullet points may help.

Comment: Newlines (Enter key) might help as well. And code is clearer than English.

Comment: I gave yous ome good code to use but really you should rethink your design. Why have buttons in classes? Are the classes derived from buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your class, assign event handlers for the click event on the buttons so when you add them to the form and they're clicked the event handler will fire off inside of your class so you can access the class properties.

Otherwise, add the class reference to the button's Tag property.

```
   class Class1
    {

        public Button MyButton { get; set; }

        public Class1()
        {
            MyButton = new Button();
            MyButton.Click += new EventHandler(MyButton_Click);
        }

        void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Do code here
        }

    }

public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Class1 c1 = new Class1();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            c1.MyButton.Width = 100;
            c1.MyButton.Height = 100;
            c1.MyButton.Top = 0;
            c1.MyButton.Left = 0;
            this.Controls.Add(c1.MyButton);


        }
```

OR

```
class Class1 : IButtonClass
    {

        public Button MyButton { get; set; }

        public Class1()
        {
            MyButton = new Button();
            MyButton.Tag = this;        
        }

        public void DoSoemthing()
        {
            //Do something
        }

    }

    interface IButtonClass
    {
        void DoSoemthing();
    }

public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Class1 c1 = new Class1();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            c1.MyButton.Width = 100;
            c1.MyButton.Height = 100;
            c1.MyButton.Top = 0;
            c1.MyButton.Left = 0;
            this.Controls.Add(c1.MyButton);

            c1.MyButton.Click += new EventHandler(MyButton_Click);
        }

    void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IButtonClass c = ((Button)sender).Tag as IButtonClass;
        c.DoSoemthing();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the button click event, you can try

```
    void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine((sender as Button).Parent.Name);
    }
```

Comment: wrong this shows 'Form1' instead of class name. sender is the SENDER of the event, not the parent of the control

Comment: @DustinDavis for button click,  sender is the Button and Button is usually present in a parent container like a Form which could be the OP's class.

Comment: From what I read, he wants the class the button is contained in, not the form. Parent will be set by the container (form1) not the class it's in.

Comment: then again it's hard to read so maybe you're correct and i'm off